# unable to load data in own table of database on dev profile inmomery in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Hello Everyone,

I am working on jhipster.I have created a database on dev profile and it is created  fine.but when i will try to load data into table using csv file then getting a exception.Please help me.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
```

Thanks in advance.

```
        email;firstName;middleName;lastName;sex;aboutYou;dateOfBirth;password;picture;isActive;createdDate
        test@gmail.com;charn;jeet;singh;b;aboutme;NULL;b8f57d6d6ec0a60dfe2e20182d4615b12e321cad9e2979e0b9f81e0d6eda78ad9b6dcfe53e4e22d1;NULL;1;NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you hit a specific bug in Spring Boot, which masks your original exception:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/253

In order to see your "real" exception, either:

- Migrate to the latest "SNAPSHOT" version of Spring Boot, as it looks to be solved now
- Remove the configuration from your AsyncConfiguration class, which is responsible for this bug